# How to display two controls aligned horizontally in a custom Ribbon XML

Tags: vsto, office-interop, ribbon-control, ribbonx

In a `group` of a `custom tab` of a `Ribon XML` of a custom `VSTO` WORD AddIn, I need to display an `editBox` aligned `horizontally` inline with a `checkBox`. How can I achieve that? Following displays both the controls aligned vertically one after the other:

```
<tab idMso="TabAddIns">  
    <group id="ContentGroup" label="Content">  
        <editBox id="editBoxID" label="Insert Text"  
             screentip="Text" onAction="getText"/>  
        <checkBox id="checkBoxID" label="Enable" />  
    </group>  
</tab>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a box, with a horizontal boxStyle.

```
<group id="groupid" label="Content">
  <box id="ContentGroup" boxStyle="horizontal">
    <editBox id="editBoxID" label="Insert Text" />
    <checkBox id="checkBoxID" label="Enable" />
  </box>
</group>
```

[image: Result of this ribbon XML]